# Swift multiple upload files or images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, image-uploading

I have to multiple upload images/videos from a gallery or camera and also a file to my website hosting.

Somebody can help me?

I tried many codes but don't work, sorry I'm new to Swift.

I made it in Android now I need it for iOS and I saw it is very difficult to find a tutorial about it.

I just found this [tutorial](https://jmsliu.com/3241/select-and-upload-multiple-photos-from-gallery-or-camera-in-ios.html).

But don't know how to put it in my code if someone can help me.

And `ELCImagePickerController` not installed through pods file, a guy told me through Facebook it is too older

Comment: You can use `DKImagePickerController` [https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController)

Comment: thanks @LinhQuangPham , but how i connect with the tutorial i posted? or how can i upload multiple images to server?

Comment: https://medium.com/@hanifsgy/alamofire-multipart-with-parameters-upload-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-swift-a4abada24ae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this https://github.com/opalorange/OpalImagePicker multiple upload images/videos from a gallery.

```
import UIKit
import OpalImagePicker  

class MultipleImagesUploadVC: UIViewController,OpalImagePickerControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Variable Declaration
var arryOfImages = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       let imagePicker = OpalImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self
        imagePicker.maximumSelectionsAllowed = 1
        imagePicker.allowedMediaTypes = Set([PHAssetMediaType.image]) //you can select only images set this
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImages images: [UIImage]){
    //print(images)
     self.arryOfImages = images   
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.singUpAPI()
}

func singUpAPI(){
    let params:NSMutableDictionary = [:] //Optional for extra parameter
    print(params.dict2json())
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for imageData in self.arryOfImages {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)!, withName: "images[1][]", fileName: "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

        for (key, value) in params
        {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key as? String ?? "")
        }
    }, to:ServerAPI.KSignup, method:.post, headers: ["Accept" : "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"]) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    print(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while requesting")
                    return
                }
                if let jsonResponse = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                    print(jsonResponse)
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    //let dict = jsonResponse["result"] as? NSDictionary ?? [:]

                    let msg = jsonResponse["message"] as? String ?? ""
                    let status = jsonResponse["status"] as? Int ?? 0
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if status == 1{
                        self.showAlert(title: Appname, message: msg)
                    }else if status == 3{
                        self.ShowAlertWithResult(title: Appname, message: "Session expired please login again", isYesNo: false, yesTitle: "Login", noTitle: "", completion: { (result) in
                            if result == true{
                                let welcomeVC = MainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelComeVC") as! WelComeVC
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(welcomeVC, animated: true)
                            }
                        })
                    }else{
                        self.showAlert(title: Appname, message: msg)
                    }
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have to change ServerAPI with my base url and Ksignup with my file to upload?

Comment: What version of alamofire is used here? Do you have php part?

Comment: ServerAPI.KSignup your file upload url, no php part sorry

Comment: Alamofire Version (4.8.1)

Comment: Thanks !!! this code is working perfectly , how can i do to select images and videos too ?

Comment: (https://github.com/opalorange/OpalImagePicker) this link to use select images and videos.